# Can email builders be embedded into a site and allow managers to edit only a certain part?

Tags: html, email, templates, sendgrid, mailgun

I want managers on my site to have the ability to build email templates and insert variables for values that they want from my database.
I know there are lots of email builders out there.
Do any of these email builders allow me to embed the email building part into my site as an iframe or something similar.

Also I want the mangers to be allowed to edit only one part of the email is that an option?
Can I create 3 different emailing templates top, middle, bottom.
Allow the manager to edit only the middle part?

I tried using Mailgun which allows me to create a template and insert varibles.
I then allow the managers on my site in tell me what these variables should be.

However I would prefer if they can get a user friendly way to do it instead of just inserting text.